# Why is my Firestore documents' array field always only updated with one less item than the array I send from the front end?

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to update a Firestore document once I save files to Google Cloud Storage. I want to send an array of URLs of the stored files to a document in Firestore as follows...

```
(attachments: [ {url: "fileone.jpeg", ...}, {url: "filetwo.jpeg", ...}, ...]).
```

This array of URLs are created at the front end by using firebases `getDownloadURL()`. I can successfully update my document but the array in the updated document always holds one less item than the array created at the front end. When `console.log`-ing the array stored in memory (to be sent to firestore) I see that the value within parentheses that preceeds the `[{},{}]` is one less than array.length as well.

What console logging the fileUrls array (stored in memory to be sent to firestore) shows even though `fileUrls.length === 3` and expanding this below line shows all three URL containing objects starting at index 0 :

```
fileUrls: > (2) [{…}, {…}]
```

Here is the code from implementing this update process:

```
let fileUrls = [];               // <<-- Array for file urls to be stored
let promises = [];

for (const file of state.post.files) {
  const fileRef = storage.ref().child(`my file path`);
  const p = fileRef.put(file)
    .then(snapshot => {
      fileRef.getDownloadURL()
        .then(url => {
          fileUrls.push({ url: url, type: file.type })  // Adding urls to arr
        })
    })

  promises.push(p);
}

const all = Promise.all(promises);
all
  .then(() => {
    submissionRef.update({         // <<<--- Updating document created prior.
      attachments: fileUrls
    })
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are waiting for the file to finish uploading, but you're not waiting until the download URL is fetched.  You'll need to involve the promise returned by getDownloadURL into the array of promises passed to Promise.all().  Try returning its promise from the `then` callback for your file upload:

```
  const p = fileRef.put(file)
    .then(snapshot => {
      // add a return here to chain the promise returned by getDownloadURL()
      // with the promise returned by put()
      return fileRef.getDownloadURL()
        .then(url => {
          fileUrls.push({ url: url, type: file.type })  // Adding urls to arr
        })
    })
```

Consider instead using async/await syntax to avoid all these callbacks and make the code easier to read.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works :) I cant publicly upvote you I have less than 15 reputation :/

Comment: You could probably still accept the answer as correct?